# How to build a generic function to print out a list of attribute for a previous list in Python 3.3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, generic-list, generic-programming, generic-collections

```
from collections import namedtuple
Book = namedtuple('Book', 'author title genre year price instock')

BSI = [
    Book("JK Rowling", "Harry Potter", "Fantasy", 1997, 10.00, 50),
    Book("Harper Lee", "To Kill a Mockingbird", "Fiction", 1960, 15.00, 100),
    Book("Dan Brown", "Da Vinci Code", "Thriller", 2003, 20.00, 500),
    Book("Mr. Python", "How to Python", "Technology", 2010, 40.00, 10),
    Book("Stephen King", "It", "Horror", 1986, 50.00, 10),
    Book("Some Guy", "Time Traveling", "Technology", 2020, 800.00, 256)
]

def Book_collection_attribute (BSI: list, attribute: str) -> list:
    '''Print out the list of the specific attribute of the list of Book collection'''
    for i in BSI:
        print(i.attribute)
    return BSI
    print(Book_collection_attribute(BSI,'title'))
```

My goal is to build a generic function to print out a list of attribute for a previous list(in this example is the Book list and 1 of its attribute: title or genre or price). Can I do this in Python 3.3?

Keep getting error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ntt2k\Desktop\ICS 31\lab3.py", line 133, in <module>
    print(Book_collection_attribute(BSI,'title'))
  File "C:\Users\ntt2k\Desktop\ICS 31\lab3.py", line 131, in Book_collection_attribute
    print(i.attribute)
AttributeError: 'Book' object has no attribute 'attribute'
```

Comment: If you're trying to use attribute names dynamically, why are you using a `namedtuple` instead of just using a `dict` (or a class inheriting from or using a `dict`)? The whole point of `namedtuple` is to give you _static_ attributes, that you look up by having their names in the source code.

Comment: Also, if you really do need to deconstruct a `namedtuple` for some reason, you can always access an ordered list of its attribute names as `i_fields`, or convert it to an `OrderedDict` with `i._asdict()`.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
print(i.attribute)
```

to

```
print(getattr(i, attribute)) 
#or if you want to specify a default, 
#print(getattr(i, attribute, ''))
```

Since `attribute` is a parameter, you need to extract the object's attribute using [`getattr`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr) instead of just doing `i.attribute`.

Answer (score 1):

The general-purpose solution for looking up attributes by name is, as explained by karthikr, [`getattr`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#getattr): `getattr(i, 'foo')` is the same as `i.foo`, and `getattr(i, attribute)` allows you to use a dynamic string just as easy as the literal `'foo'`.

If you're specifically dealing with [`namedtuple`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/collections.html#namedtuple-factory-function-for-tuples-with-named-fields)s, you can access their field-to-index mapping in a few different ways. For example, `i._fields` gives you the (ordered) list of fields, while `i._asdict()` gives you the same values as an `OrderedDict`, so you can do `d = i._asdict()`, then just `d[attribute]`.

However, all of this raises the question of why you're using a `namedtuple` in the first place. The whole point of attribute access in general, and `namedtuple` in particular, is that it's perfect for *static* access to its attributes: where the attribute names are part of yout source code. Using it this way is akin to dynamically creating a bunch of variables, which is a bad idea, as explained [here](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html) and [here](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/05/why-you-dont-want-to-dynamically-create.html).

If you just used a `dict`—or a class that inherited from or owned one—this would be trivial, because looking up things by their name dynamically is what a `dict` is all about: `i[attribute]`.

And, even without a class, you can still write a `book` function to construct the `dict` for you, so the rest of your code looks just as nice. For example:

```
def book(author, title, genre, year, price, instock):
    return {'author': author, 'title': title, 'genre': genre, 
            'year': year, 'price': price, 'instock': instock}
```

Compare that to the code generated by your `namedtuple` (which you can see as `Book.source`) and it's a whole lot simpler. If you don't like that repetition, you can always do this:

```
def book(*args):
    return dict(zip('author title genre year price instock'.split(), args))
```

Of course sometimes you have a case where you *mostly* want to access attributes statically, but *occasionally* want to access them dynamically. And in that case, `getattr` is exactly the right tool for the job.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers and very useful references provided. :D

I have to use "namedtuple" because part of my class assignment. We have not been taught about dictionary yet.

Anyway again so appreciate for the answers.

Comment: @TrungNguyen: Your teacher taught you about `namedtuple` before `dict`? Seriously? You may need a new teacher…

Comment: @TrungNguyen Are you sure you did not miss the class on `dict` ?